# Создание сетевой папки http

Tags: http, сеть, администрирование, https, ftp

Работаю на windows 10. Есть сетевой адрес http://some_name.ru/folder_name в интернете, заходя на который я вижу список файлов и папок. Внизу на странице надпись:
Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g mod_log_rotate/1.00 PHP/7.4.10 Server at some_name.ru Port 80
Можно ли каким либо образом сделать на локальной машине сетевую папку в проводнике или в каком либо приложении для удобного манипулирования файлами, например, для копирования?
UPD: при создании сетевого окружения выходит вот такая ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Total Commander или что-нибудь подобное, ftp-клиент

Comment: в проводнике ПКМ на "Этот компьютер" - Добавить новый элемент в сетевое окружение

Comment: Если там нет `webdav`, то нормальными способами - нет.